# Loop Iteration Efficient

Tags: loops, performance

You have a loop that iterates over 1,000 items. You want to add a newline to every four items. The items are in an array structure that have numeric index starting at 0. How do you do it?

Comment: Can you show where is it that you get stuck? What code have you written for it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean - `You want to add a newline to every four items.`

Comment: `<humor>`I'd wait a bit before accepting an anwer: you can bet the end-all-be-all answer will soon be posted, as someone has taken the time to downvote each and every answer to date; there must be some superior answer brewing.`<humor>`

Comment: +1 as welcome to SO. My answer below.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    // you want to 'do it' with list[i] here

    if (0 == (i+1)%4))
    {
           // 'you want to add a new line' here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case what you are really trying to ask is "How do I print these items, four to a line?" here's one way

```
int nOnLine = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
  // print item i
  nOnLine++;
  if (nOnLine >= 4){
    // print newline
    nOnLine = 0;
  }
}
if (nOnLine > 0){
  // print newline
  nOnLine = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 4) {
 // add to the item
}
```

The above iterates over every fourth item instead of every single item.

Comment: Why the downvote? This iterates on every fourth item... whats the problem?

Comment: Well, if that is why i was downvoted, then I guess I dont really care. For a minute I thought someone was trying to tell me there was a problem with the approach that I just wasnt seeing.

Comment: good point. I saw it happening and I was mystified. I sort of jumped to the conclusion that the OP voted me up, and the other two down, perhaps thinking that he was supposed to. Someone else must have been at it. Sorry to bother you, @John

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i=3;i<len;i=i+4) { // where len is the length of your array
  ary[i]+='\n';        // use string append operator of your language.
}
```

which will add a newline to every fourth item, i.e. items 3, 7, 11, etc.

EDIT

Changed to fulfill the OP's criteria.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why was this answer downvoted? I believe it fulfills the OP's criteria, no?

Comment: I'm not the mysterious downvoter, but: this answer - and @Brad's - adds a newline after the first item, and every four items *after that*, which isn't the same as adding a newline after every *fourth* item. (hint: the first index that should receive a newline is **3**)